# How to create Multiple tables with Next Button or Tab leading to another Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small issue which i don't really know how to handle, I created a form with 3 segments (giving those segments class of tab) and now i want to create a next and previous button to the form which will allow user to navigate to `tabs`. But by default or at loading i just want the `first Tab` to be currently visible.

```css
.col-lg-9 {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.borderexample {
    border-color: rgb(75, 218, 75);
    border-style: solid;
    border: 40px;
    padding: 1rem;
}

body {
    background-color: gray;
}

.form-inline .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-inline .form-group {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="fillForm" action="#">
    <div class="tab"><span class="info">Corporate Information: (fill appropriate box)</span>
      <br /> <br />
      <div class="form-group">
        Company Name:
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CName">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Company_office_address">Company Office Address: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Company_office_address">
      </div>
      <!--inline form starts here-->
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          <label for="town">Town:* </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Town" placeholder="Town">
        </div>
        <div class=" form-group" id="form-inline">
          City:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          State:* <input type="text" class="form-control" id="State" placeholder="State">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Country:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" placeholder="Country">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Incorporation Number:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Inumber">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Date Incorporated:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dincorporated">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          State of Incorporation:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="S_incorporation">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Country of Incorporated:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="C_incorporated">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Company Website:*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="C_website">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Company Email:*
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="C_email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          FAX (if applicable):*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Fax">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Company Phone Number:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="C_phone">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      Tax Identification Number (TIN):*
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TIN">
    </div>

    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        Occupation:
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="occupation">
      </div>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <div class="form-group">
        BVN:
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bvn">
      </div>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <div class="form-group">
        Income Source:
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="incomeSource">
      </div>
    </div><br /> <br />


    <div class="tab"><span class="info">Other Relevant Information</span>

      <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
        <label for="RLA">Risk Location Address(Where applicable)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RLA" placeholder="Risk Location">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
        <label for="RLA">Risk Location Address(Where applicable)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RLA" placeholder="Risk Location">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="RLA">Risk Location Address(Where applicable)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RLA" placeholder="Risk Location">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="RLA">Risk Location Address(Where applicable)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RLA" placeholder="Risk Location">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="RLA">Risk Location Address(Where applicable)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RLA" placeholder="Risk Location">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="RLA">Risk Location Address(Where applicable)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RLA" placeholder="Risk Location">
      </div>


    </div>
  </form>


  </div><br /> <br />
  <!--The second Tab Ends Here-->


  <div class="tab"><span class="info">BROKER'S INFORMATION</span>
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Brokers">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        NAICOM Reg. No.:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Naicom">
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="broker"> (The Broker hereby certify that all the required documents as requested by law
      collected from the Client)
    </span>
    <br /><br />

    <div class="form-group">
      Signature & Stamp/Seal of Broker
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Signature">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br /><br />
  <!--the Brokers tab ends here-->
  </form>
  </div><br /><br />
  <!--The first Tab ends here-->

  </div>
  <!--Container ends here-->

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please add some `CSS` if you have any

Comment: .col-lg-9{
    float:right; margin-top: 0px; padding:0px; 
}

.borderexample{
    border-color: rgb(75, 218, 75);
    border-style: solid;
    border: 40px;
    padding: 1rem;
}

body{
    background-color: gray;
}

.form-inline .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.form-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.form-inline .form-group { margin-right:20px;}

Comment: There is another class named 'form-inline' b/t first two sections. It belongs to which section?

Comment: We use `index.php` in `PHP` if we want to set a default home page. By using simple `html` i think its not possible. How ever you can navigate to other pages by using `<a>` tag.

Comment: I thought there is a way to do this using Javascript or javascript library (Jquery).

Comment: You can simply use `<a>` to navigate using next and previous `<button>` w/o using any `JS`

Comment: Now can you explain more because i don't just want to create a link next button but i want to display the first tab then have Next button to lead me to the next tab. which will also have a previous button to lead me back to the first button

Comment: Something like function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";

Comment: you don't want to create three files?

Comment: In this case you can wrap all code in three tabs and use `display:block` for one tab on which currently user is and `display:none` for other two tabs. You can change these displays by using `js functions` which are called by clicking on next and previous buttons

Comment: I updated my answer. If it solves your problem please my answer as accepted. Or if there is any other problem then you can ask in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use three `.html` files and paste the code of each of three `tabs` in these three files then you can give the link of next and previous file of `tab` by adding there links to anchor tag `<a>` on the next and previous `<button>` as follow;

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/M9eOGHuGqRnAv3LYhVc8?p=preview)

**Note:** I added external IDE as its not possible to create three `.html` files in Snippet of SO.

**Update:** In case you don't want to make three files and give there references in each other, you can use `JS` as follows;

```js
tab = document.getElementsByClassName('tab')
btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn1')
tab[1].style.display = 'none'
tab[2].style.display = 'none'
btn[0].classList.add("disabled")

function next() {
    if (tab[0].style.display != 'none') {
        tab[0].style.display = 'none'
        tab[2].style.display = 'none'
        tab[1].style.display = 'block'
        btn[0].classList.remove("disabled")
    }
    else if(tab[1].style.display != 'none'){
        tab[0].style.display = 'none'
        tab[2].style.display = 'block'
        tab[1].style.display = 'none'
        btn[1].classList.add("disabled")        
    }
}

function previous() {
    if (tab[0].style.display != 'none') {
        
    }
    else if(tab[1].style.display != 'none'){
        tab[0].style.display = 'block'
        tab[2].style.display = 'none'
        tab[1].style.display = 'none'
        btn[0].classList.add("disabled")        
    }
    else{
        tab[0].style.display = 'none'
        tab[2].style.display = 'none'
        tab[1].style.display = 'block'
        btn[1].classList.remove("disabled")
    }
}
// alert(tab[1].style.display)
```

```css
.disabled{
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #666666;}
.disabled:hover{
    cursor: default;
}
.col-lg-9 {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.borderexample {
    border-color: rgb(75, 218, 75);
    border-style: solid;
    border: 40px;
    padding: 1rem;
}

body {
    background-color: gray;
}

.form-inline .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-inline .form-group {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="fillForm" action="#">
    <div class="tab"><span class="info">Corporate Information: (fill appropriate box)</span>
      <br /> <br />
      <div class="form-group">
        Company Name:
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CName">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Company_office_address">Company Office Address: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Company_office_address">
      </div>
      <!--inline form starts here-->
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          <label for="town">Town:* </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Town" placeholder="Town">
        </div>
        <div class=" form-group" id="form-inline">
          City:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="City">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          State:* <input type="text" class="form-control" id="State" placeholder="State">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Country:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" placeholder="Country">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Incorporation Number:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Inumber">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Date Incorporated:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dincorporated">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          State of Incorporation:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="S_incorporation">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Country of Incorporated:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="C_incorporated">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Company Website:*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="C_website">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Company Email:*
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="C_email">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          FAX (if applicable):*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Fax">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
          Company Phone Number:*
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="C_phone">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        Tax Identification Number (TIN):*
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TIN">
      </div>

      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          Occupation:
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="occupation">
        </div>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <div class="form-group">
          BVN:
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bvn">
        </div>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <div class="form-group">
          Income Source:
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="incomeSource">
        </div>
      </div><br /> <br />
    </div>



    <div class="tab"><span class="info">Other Relevant Information</span>

      <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
        <label for="RLA">Risk Location Address(Where applicable)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RLA" placeholder="Risk Location">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" id="form-inline">
        <label for="RLA">Risk Location Address(Where applicable)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RLA" placeholder="Risk Location">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="RLA">Risk Location Address(Where applicable)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RLA" placeholder="Risk Location">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="RLA">Risk Location Address(Where applicable)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RLA" placeholder="Risk Location">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="RLA">Risk Location Address(Where applicable)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RLA" placeholder="Risk Location">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="RLA">Risk Location Address(Where applicable)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RLA" placeholder="Risk Location">
      </div>


    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="tab"><span class="info">BROKER'S INFORMATION</span>
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Brokers">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        NAICOM Reg. No.:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Naicom">
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="broker"> (The Broker hereby certify that all the required documents as requested by law
      collected from the Client)
    </span>
    <br /><br />

    <div class="form-group">
      Signature & Stamp/Seal of Broker
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Signature">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="previous()" class="btn1">Previous</button>  <button onclick="next()" class="btn1">Next</button>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @JudeObiejesi I updated my answer. If it solves your problem please my answer as accepted. Or if there is any other problem then you can ask in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var currentTab = 0;
    showTab(currentTab);

    function showTab(n) {

        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        x[n].style.display = "block";

        if (n == 0) {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
        }
        if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
        }

        fixStepIndicator(n)
    }
    function nextPrev(n) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

        if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;

        x[currentTab].style.display = "none";

        currentTab = currentTab + n;

        if (currentTab >= x.length) {
            document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
            return false;
        }
        showTab(currentTab);
    }
```

I think something like should have been similar to what i was expecting